# Why is it that in DSA, the order of the subgroup, $q$, is chosen such that it divides $p - 1$?

Tags: dsa, key-generation

Consider the [DSA key generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Parameter_generation):

1. A large prime $p$ is chosen;
2. A smaller modulus $q$ is chosen such that $p - 1$ is a multiple of $q$;
3. A generator $g$ s.t. $\operatorname{ord}_p(g) = q$ is chosen.

My question is -- why do we require that $p - 1$ be a multiple of $q$?  Is there any underlying mathematics I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: [Lagrange's theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29)

Comment: That is, if $q$ isn't a divisor of $p-1$, then there won't be a subgroup of size $q$

Comment: Thanks guys.  I _almost_ thought of it myself.  Feel free to write an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: It's actually done the other direction: find prime q of the desired size (e.g. 256 bits) then find prime p = kq+1 of the desired size (e.g. 2048 bits). 'find' can either be 'choose a random candidate and test (Miller-Rabin plus optional Lucas)' or 'construct from half-size primes, recursively (Shawe-Taylor) and tweak'. See A.1 C.3 C.6 of FIPS186, on the NIST CSRC website on days the President isn't having a temper tantrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was [noted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31225/why-is-it-that-in-dsa-the-order-of-the-subgroup-q-is-chosen-such-that-it-di#comment72423_31225) [in the comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31225/why-is-it-that-in-dsa-the-order-of-the-subgroup-q-is-chosen-such-that-it-di#comment72424_31225) the reason for $q$ having to divide $p-1$ is [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29):

> **Lagrange's theorem** [...], states that
>   for any finite group $G$, the order (number of elements) of every
>   subgroup $H$ of $G$ divides the order of $G$.

In the case of DSA we are working in subgroups of $\mathbb F_p$ (which has order $p-1$). By Lagrange's theorem every subgroup has to have an order $q$ such that $q$ divides $p-1$.